# catkin_package() include dir 'include' does not exist

Tags: ros, catkin-make, include, viso2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install **viso2_ros** package from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros), when I encounter the following error while I **catkin_make**

```
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:296 (message):
    catkin_package() include dir 'include' does not exist relative to
    '/home/tonystark/vision_odometry/src/dlut_smartrob/dlut_motor_hokuyo'
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
   dlut_smartrob/dlut_motor_hokuyo/CMakeLists.txt:50 (catkin_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/tonystark/vision_odometry/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
  See also "/home/tonystark/vision_odometry/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Can you please tell me how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

If the way am installing is wrong, can you please point me towards the correct direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213694/catkin_package()-include-dir-%27include%27-does-not-exist/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I don't see a viso2 related error here, but a include error in your dlut_smartrob package. Check the CMakeLists.txt of your package to see if you are including a non existing directory.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-14**:
I got the package from the link mentioned

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-14**:
can you please point to where I can look for it?

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-14**:
fatal error: pcl/point_cloud.h: No such file or directory
I got this error while compiling/installing. Any ideas if you had the same?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-07-14**:
Remove the word include [from this line](https://github.com/ZhuangYanDLUT/dlut_smartrob/blob/groovy-devel/dlut_motor_hokuyo/CMakeLists.txt#L63), and check if you have PCL libraries (libpcl-1.7-all) installed.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2015-07-14**:
issues resolved. thanks,! :)